# Twitter bootstrap modal using angularui

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

Hi right now I'm using an angularui modal to pop up after another when the user presses the ok button.  The problem is everytime I transition to the next modal, the screen does an annoying flash before the entry of the next modal (don't look at the modal, look at the background and you'll see a flash).

I believe it is because the first modal's transitioning out effect.  How could I make it so I remove that transitioning out flash effect?

Here is a plunkr to show an example.  Thanks

http://plnkr.co/edit/AJ6TgULKXP3AmlxaIEcx?p=preview

Actually for some reason on the plunkr it's not showing the flash during the modal transition but for mine it is.

Update:
I figured out the answer.  You need to have all the ng-templates in one file, you cannot separate them.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Google chrome and I don't see a flash.  Maybe its browser specific?

Comment: Well I don't see the flash as well in the plunkr. But in my project there is a flash. I'm trying to figure out why that is the case....

Comment: Before you open modal or change state give some time out likt 300 or 400 using $timeout function in angular , it will work